# How can i generate name attributes using asp-for that ignore the parent?

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-core, model

for example, i have this in my View:

```html
    <div class="form-group">
       <label asp-for="Departamento.Departamento" class="control-label"></label>
       <input name="Departamento" class="form-control" />
       <span asp-validation-for="Departamento.Departamento" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
```

as you can see in input i have name="Departamento", because in my model i have string Departamento..
i want to use asp-for="Departamento",  but since my model is a combination of two models i cannot acess directly and it will be asp-for="Departamentos.Departamento"... so that gives me the wrong text and wont insert in database... any help?

EDIT: my models:

````
    public class Departamentos
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Departamento { get; set; }
            public string Autor { get; set; }
            public int Ordem { get; set; }
            public DateTime Criado { get; set; }
            public List<AreasDepartamentos> Areas { get; set; }
    
    
        }
    ```
````

```
public class AreasDepartamentos
    {
        public int AreasId { get; set; }
        public Areas Area { get; set; }

        public int DepartamentoId { get; set; }
        public Departamentos Departamento { get; set; }


    }
```

```
My controller post :
´´´

    [HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Departamento,Autor,Ordem")] Departamentos departamentos, int[] areas)
            {
                List<AreasDepartamentos> areasLista = new List<AreasDepartamentos>();
               
                foreach(var i in areas)
                {
                    areasLista.Add(new AreasDepartamentos() { AreasId = i, DepartamentoId = departamentos.Id });
                }
    
                departamentos.Areas = areasLista;
                departamentos.Criado = DateTime.Now;
    
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    _context.Add(departamentos);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                }
            return View(departamentos);
            }

´´´
```

Comment: It could work well with tag helper in my project.Could you share your models?And what did you use,mvc or razor pages?Also,please share what's the model you want to receive in your backend.

Comment: I will edit the question with models in question, they prob are a litle confusing since im new to this but there you go :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case,it seems you could only receive the name of `Departamento`.`asp-for="Departamentos.Departamento"` would generate html:`name="Departamentos.Departamento"`.To only pass the `Departmento`,you could ignore the parent name in the backend by using `[Bind(Prefix="Departamentos")]`:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Test([Bind(Prefix = "Departamentos")] YourModel model)
{
    return View();
}
```

Note:Be sure which is the data in asp-for.Your code uses `asp-for="Departamento.Departamento"` but your description is `asp-for="Departamentos.Departamento"`.

Comment: Yes it is asp-for="Departamento.Departamento".  
This is my post action:
``` [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Departamento,Autor,Ordem")] Departamentos departamentos, int[] areas)

I understood why add prefix, but then i cant have the fields in Bind in the front of that, it will still work ? Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: I tried to delete the fields in Bind and put prefix but it didnt work... It still gives me an error if i use asp-for in the View :/

Comment: Bind prefix is to ignore the parent name in the backend instead of frontend.The tag helper still should be `asp-for="Departamento.Departamento"`.

Comment: This was perfect! Thank you very much!  :D